# Inconsistent cypher result with bas64 output encode

Tags: node.js, base64, node-crypto

I need to cypher a textual payload, save it somewhere and after a while read it and decypher it again.

I started with some code and I noticed that there is an inconsistent behavior when I tell nodejs standard `cypher` to give me the output in base64. Some characters at the end of the result are missing. Changing the output encoding solve completely the problem. See the example.

```js
import crypto from 'crypto'

const key = 'base64:Zm9vYmFy'

const payload = 'the cat is on the table'

const cypher = crypto.createCipheriv('RC4', key, null)
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('RC4', key, null)

// Missing characters on result
const cypheredPayload = cypher.update(payload, 'ascii', 'base64')
const decipheredPayload = decipher.update(cypheredPayload, 'base64', 'ascii')

// All works fine
//const cypheredPayload = cypher.update(payload, 'ascii', 'ascii')
//const decipheredPayload = decipher.update(cypheredPayload, 'ascii', 'ascii')

console.log(decipheredPayload)
```

The result when I choose the output as `base64` is `the cat is on the tab` (the last two characters are missing), if I switch to the version with the `ascii` output there is no problem.

What's happening here?

Comment: The two `final()` calls that finalize encryption and decryption are missing (s. e.g. [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cipherfinaloutputencoding) for the `Cipher` class). For Base64 encoding this leads to data loss during encryption for the posted example.

Comment: Also, for encryption, not `ascii` but `binary` should be used as output encoding (even if `ascii` works for this example, it won't work in general).

Comment: @Topaco you are right! I fall in the very strange use of the cypher class! If you write your response I will accept it